# I have a issue trying to send information to my database

Tags: mysql, express

This is my app.post

```
app.post("/productos", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { nombre, precio, urlImagen, categoria } = req.body;
        console.log("Datos del formulario:", req.body);

        const connection = await database.getConnection();
        const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO producto (nombre, precio, urlImagen, categoria) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [nombre, precio, urlImagen, categoria]);

        if (result.affectedRows > 0) {
            res.json({ message: "Producto agregado correctamente" });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ error: "Error al agregar el producto" });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});
```

And this is my button inside of a modal in bootstrap

```
 <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="http://localhost:4000/productos" method="post">
                <!-- Campo de Producto -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="producto">Producto</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producto" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Campo de Precio -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio del Producto" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Campo de Imagen -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imagen" name="urlImagen" placeholder="URL de la Imagen" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Campo de Categoría -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="categoria">Categoría</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="categoria" name="categoria" placeholder="Categoría del Producto" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Botón para enviar el formulario -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Producto</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The request arrive to my database but is EMPTY

[MYSQL Database request empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbvQg.png)

i want the request arrive to the data base with the information that i insert in the form.

Comment: What does `console.log("Datos del formulario:", req.body);` print to the console?

Comment: "Datos del formulario:{}"

Comment: OK this is quite common. You need to use `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));` before any of your route handlers. That uses the `bodyParser` middleware to parse your forms.

Answer (score 0):

as @jQueeny said you have to use middleware `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));` in your app.js or wherever you defined your routes but before your routes.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(expressValidator());

app.use('/api', routes);
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>
  console.log(`listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`),
);
```

The express.urlencoded() middleware function is used to extract the data from the request body and add it to the request object in the form of req.body